# What is the equation of $F(x)$, given the outputs?

Tags: functions, closed-form

I can't figure out the equation of $F(x)$, if any, for the following sequence of numbers.

$$225, 232, 244, 262, 287, 318, 354, 397, 446, 502, 563, 630, 704, 784, 870, 962$$

The equation should evaluate $x$ as:

$$F(0) = 225$$
$$F(1) = 232$$
$$F(2) = 244$$
etc.

Can somebody figure out what $F(x)$ is, or point me to a resource to help me find a solution?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation

Comment: @Mystic: someone already  mentioned the approach and you should get $f(x) = \dfrac{211 x^{15}}{59439744000}-\dfrac{713 x^{14}}{1779148800}+\frac{11791 x^{13}}{574801920}-\dfrac{603401 x^{12}}{958003200}+\dfrac{185857579 x^{11}}{14370048000}-\dfrac{16324801 x^{10}}{87091200}+\dfrac{721251973 x^9}{365783040}-\dfrac{1327725473 x^8}{87091200}+\dfrac{113295343321 x^7}{1306368000}-\dfrac{15658309981 x^6}{43545600}+\dfrac{13896522229 x^5}{13063680}-\dfrac{258934011737 x^4}{119750400}+\dfrac{12850299193621 x^3}{4540536000}-\dfrac{1822875161 x^2}{864864}+\dfrac{18556019 x}{27720}+225$

Comment: Does $F$ have to have any specific form?  I see somebody posted an answer in the form of a polynomial.  But if there are no restrictions then just connect the points with straight line segments (piecewise linear) and call it a day.

Comment: The second differences are $5, 6, 7, 6, 5, 7, 6, 7, 5, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6$.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a closed form but an expression exact except for the last two terms ($+1$) is :
($[x]$ is the nearest integer)
$$F(n-1)=\left[\left(\frac{7n}4\right)^2-3n+225.4\right]$$

Comment: An exact function would be $$F(n-1)=\left[\left(\frac{7n}4\right)^2-3n+225.4+\exp(x-16)\right]$$ but I am not sure that the OP hoped to get a "closed form" (the tag was added) and consider the (deleted) quadratic fit by Henry W very appropriate! An [alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=bestfit%20%281%2C%20225%29%2C%20%282%2C232%29%2C%20%283%2C244%29%2C%20%284%2C262%29%2C%20%285%2C287%29%2C%20%286%2C318%29%2C%20%287%2C354%29%2C%20%288%2C397%29%2C%20%289%2C446%29%2C%20%2810%2C502%29) link may help too.